# azure keyvault certificate autorenew

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault

When azure keyvault's certificate gets auto renewed will the previously added tags persist on new version ?  If the previously added tags are not persisted on new version any workaround for this to carry forward the tags during auto cert renewal .

Comment: Hi, did you have a chance to test my reply? The OP in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63317097/do-keyvault-tags-get-cloned-during-auto-renewal/63350158#63350158) I mentioned also verified it, it is correct. So if you don't have other concerns,could you [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? (not up-vote).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the previous tags will persist in the new version when the certificate gets auto-renewed.

I provided my test steps and screenshots [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63350158/9455659), you could refer to it for more details.