# Do keyvault tags get cloned during auto-renewal?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

My use case is managing certificates that are:-

- issued via Digicert API,
- set to auto-renew.

**If I set any tags on the latest version of cert, does it get cloned to the next issued version via auto-renew?**

I didn't see any documentation and it confused me since tags are set by going to a specific version of the certificate, not on the main page where all versions are listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I set any tags on the latest version of cert, does it get cloned to the next issued version via auto-renew?

Per my test, the tags will also be cloned to the next version.

---

If you have some concerns, you could also try it by yourself. Just generate a self-signed certificate with the `Validity Period (in months)` and `Percentage Lifetime` like below. After about `7.2` hours later, it will generate a new version, just check it, you will find the tags are existing.

**Note:** Don't modify `Issuance Policy` to test, issuance policies only affect certificates that will be issued in the future. Modifying this issuance policy will not affect any existing certificates.

[image]

**Test result:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Joy Wang, I was able to verify with the exact steps you mentioned. I wasn't really sure on how to trigger the renew sooner, `Percentage Lifetime` option did the trick! 

Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

Tags can be cloned during certificate auto-renew process in a Keyvault .We will have the document updated in a week about the same. It was something that changed recently.

Update (16th Aug):- We had engaged with the product group and had the public documentation updated on the same.

[image: tag-update-on-certs]

Comment: Hey @Shashi, after some testing, we observed that it is indeed copying certificates but we don't see that information anywhere in the docs.

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi I think you are talking about tags being copied over along with certifcates as Joy had mentioned as per the testing .If I have misunderstood this , please let me know.  I will get this verified again with the backend team and have it included in the document. and accordingly update the answer.

Comment: Sorry I meant "tags", not certificates. My bad, I can't edit my comment now. Basically, Keyvault has an undocumented feature of copying over the tags and there's no information in docs to get more concrete information about this.